# Duplicating data for use in new ArcMap project

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-management, duplication

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

I wanted to make a new project based on the same data as an existing project, so I duplicated the project file and started editing one of the layers in Editor Mode. I then went back to my original project and realised that my edits had also affected it, because as I've now realised, I didn't duplicate the data, just the container for it.

I've done a fair bit of work aside from those silly edits on the new project already so I'd rather not start again.

Is there a straightforward way of duplicating the data and pointing the new project to that new set rather than editing the originals or do I have to go into each layer and edit the data source individually?

I had a search of the site but couldn't find anything specific for my question.

Comment: are you able to give more detail about the data sources? ie: Format? Location?

Comment: This is one of the fundamental differences between GIS and CAD. In GIS the data is *not* part of the map project, so copying a project will not protect your data from manipulation.

Comment: You can create a map package https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/creating-a-map-package.htm then extract the package to a new folder, this will repoint your MXD to the new location with a duplicate of the data. This is the most straightforward method I know of. Most likely though your sub project will have common data (imagery, cadastre, road centerlines etc..) and specific data (results of geoprocessing operations, site data etc..) so be careful about versioning if you go this way.

Comment: I store data and mxd in the same folder. It is enough to copy content of that folder to another folder using windows explorer. Make sure to check "Store relative path" in mxd properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your edited data, your only hope would be to restore a previously backed-up version.  You do back up regularly, don't you?

In the future, one option to duplicate  would be to:

1. Store your data and the associated .mxd in the same folder.
2. In *File > Map Document Properties*, check the "Store Relative Pathnames..." box **on**, as shown below. Save the Map Document.

[image]

3. Run the *Package Map* tool.  This will create a single output .mpk file containing all your data, as well as the associated .mxd file.  .mpk files are analagous to .zip files.
4. Move the .mpk to a new location and  drag-n-drop it into a new Arcmap session.
5. Voila! The data and associated are now copied to the new location, independent of the original.

Comment: In general, this is a better solution than mine (see below) on the assumption that all data is required to be copied, AND that source data is not services or a large ECW etc.... But yes, overall, a bit cleaner than exporting all data individually.

Answer (score 2):

In short - **Right Click > Data > Export Data  then repoint your Data Sources**

Good question and often I find one having to explain to CAD Users where the project itself contains all the data, so don't feel silly for thinking like this - its quite common.

Think of the MXD as a template. Your layer files will be individual files on a file share somewhere. (assuming they are not databases).

The most basic way to achieve this is to go to your original MXD project and then in the Table of Conents, for each layer, Select the Layer, Right Click > Data > Export Data

This will allow you to save a copy of the data in a new location.

When you open up your new MXD, repoint the data sources for each layer item.
Again, Table of Contents, Select > Right Click > Properties > Source table > Set Data Source button.

Point to your new copies and hey presto. Start editing.

What you are doing is essentially creating a 'snapshot' of your original data. You should think about managing this snap shot some way. Archive it, name it accordingly, etc.... If this is a process you will be engaging with longer term, you definitely want to start looking at larger scale version management and archival processes and/or technology.